# Calculating Riemann sum with square root

Tags: riemann-integration, riemann-sum

[image]

I'm unsure how exactly to proceed with the sum since it involves a square root. Hints/suggestions?

Comment: What **area** does this integral represent?

Comment: area of a circle with radius 5?

Comment: Close, but off by a factor of 2.

Comment: area x 1/2, since we're only taking the positive side. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the right answer

Comment: got it...it's actually a 1/4th of the area